# Unable to inherit from a Thread Class in C# ?

Tags: c#

The class `Thread` is a sealed class meaning it cannot be inherited from and I need an instance of a reusable `Thread` that should inherit from the **Thread** class. Does anyone have an idea how i can reuse tread ?

Comment: Try composition?

Comment: What sense does a resuable thread make when a thread is not reusable from the operating point of view?

Comment: Why don't you use ThreadPool instead?

Comment: It's not my business, but you are going to do something awful and dangerous. Consider about sharing your main problem with community, and I'm sure we could find better solution.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As you yourself noted, `Thread` is a sealed class. Obviously this means you cannot inherit from it. However, you can create your own `BaseThread` class that you can inherit and override to provide custom functionality using [Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).

```
abstract class BaseThread
{
    private Thread _thread;

    protected BaseThread()
    {
        _thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.RunThread));
    }

    // Thread methods / properties
    public void Start() => _thread.Start();
    public void Join() => _thread.Join();
    public bool IsAlive => _thread.IsAlive;

    // Override in base class
    public abstract void RunThread();
}

public MyThread : BaseThread
{
    public MyThread()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public override void RunThread()
    {
        // Do some stuff
    }
}
```

You get the idea.

Comment: Edited answer to include constructor

Answer (score 5):

A preferable alternative to using Inheritance is to use Composition. Create your class and have a member of type `Thread`. Then map the methods of your class to call methods from the Thread member and add any other methods you may wish. Example:

```
public class MyThread 
{
    private Thread thread;
    // constructors

    public void Join()
    {
        thread.Join();
    }

    // whatever else...
}
```