# How to keep track of user input in C# console application?

Tags: c#, console-application, user-input

I'm making a console game using C#. I want to my program to execute a block of code any time the user hits the arrow keys. Although that sounds pretty easy, I have no idea how to do that because I'm kind of new to C#.

PS I'm working on VS for mac.

EDIT 1: I want to keep track of user input means that I don't want it to stop other tasks when the program is listening for a user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GameLogic should run in a separate thread in an endless loop.
You can keep track by listening to Console.ReadKey() in an while(true) loop endless loop on your main Thread. Everytime a Key is pressed you could throw an Event which which is handled by your other Thread.

To start a new Thread have a look at: [How do I run a simple bit of code in a new thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363377/how-do-i-run-a-simple-bit-of-code-in-a-new-thread)

A clean aproach would be to create a GameLogicWorker which holds a private Thread(The cleanest aproach in my opinion)
This answere shows how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8123600/4992212

But there are several options. You can also use async and await keywords to achieve async operations.

Comment: Good idea! I haven't thought of multithreading. But can you show me how to do multithreading in C#?

Comment: edited my answer. The second link provides an example how to implement a worker class, which you can use for your GameLogic

Comment: Thank you so much! That perfectly solved my problem! The website does not allow me to accept your answer now. I will do it a bit later.

Comment: I'm glad i was able to help :)